# Uipath(RPA) : read data from the PDF file and write to Excel file

Tags: rpa, uipath, uipath-studio

I'm trying to **convert** the **PDF** file to **excel** file in Uipath(RPA).
eg, PDF file like Bank statement, Invoice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use UiPath and not willing to develop something on your own. You could give public libraries a try. Maybe the ExcelActivies. Here the steps how to get it working:

1. Download nugpk file [image]
2. Embed that file in the package manager [image]
3. Use the "Export Pdf to Excel" activity [image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the pdf to editable and then get the data.

or **just try this [online editor](https://smallpdf.com/pdf-to-excel) to convert.**

https://smallpdf.com/pdf-to-excel